# Saving cookies via pickle aiohttp

Tags: python, queue, python-asyncio, pickle, aiohttp

I'm rewriting the library `asyncsteampy` for the current version of Steam. But when I try to save the session to a pickle file, an error occurs

```
async def create_steam_session(username, password, steam_guard, pkl_name, api_key, proxies):
    steam_client = SteamClient(username, password, f'steam_guards/{steam_guard}', api_key=api_key)
    await steam_client.login()
    return steam_client

async def authorization(username, password, steam_guard, pkl_name, api_key):
    steam_client = await create_steam_session(username, password, steam_guard, pkl_name, api_key)
    await steam_client._session.connector.close()
    with open(f'async_pkl/{pkl_name}', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(steam_client, f)
```

If I don't use `await steam_client._session.connector.close()`I get an error `TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object` I used to just delete it `'weakref' object` But then the following error appears `TypeError: cannot pickle '_contextvars.Context' object` But after `await steam_client._session.connector.close()` the following error appeared
`TypeError: cannot pickle '_queue.SimpleQueue' object`

How to solve the error `'_queue.SimpleQueue' object`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to pickle an entire client, not the cookies. This won't work as a client has open sockets and other things that could never be pickled.

I don't know what that particular library exposes, but `aiohttp.ClientSession` has a `.save()` and `.load()` method for cookies:
https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.CookieJar.save

Note that these are not stable across minor releases of aiohttp, so cookies saved in 3.9 may not load in 3.10 without a conversion script.

Comment: You helped me a lot with your answer. Is it possible to save not only the cookie but also the session?

Comment: Exactly the same answer as my first line, it holds open sockets etc. so there's no way you could restore a session correctly. Just write code to create a new session with the same parameters and load the cookies.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wrote my last comment due to a misunderstanding of the library that I am rewriting, now I understand everything